# What is the best way to execute asynchronous code inside CameraX analyze()?

Tags: android, kotlin, asynchronous, android-camerax

I'm using CameraX's image analysis use case that keeps calling the `analyze()` method in my custom `Analyzer` class. Inside `analyze()`, before doing anything else, I need to send a request to a connected device and wait for its response; the latency is very low and I'm already doing it synchronously with no issues, but I was told it's better to make it asynchronous just in case the device responds too slowly.

I know that MLKit's `process()` returns a `Task<List<T>>` and I already call `onSuccessListener { }` on it, so I was wondering if I can use a similar approach (I can't return a `Task<T>` from my function, how do I create one?). Otherwise would you suggest threads, or coroutines, or something else?

**Edit:** below there's a simplified example of what I'm trying to do. For a given frame sent by the camera I just need to perform only the current analysis in line, then I return so that `analyze()` will be called again with the next frame, on which it will perform the next analysis.

It might look hacky but it's for an app that continuously runs in foreground on a single-purpose device (let's call it *Dev A*) with no user interaction provided by touch or other conventional means, so it needs some kind of trigger to start doing what is required.

The trigger might as well be when the first image analysis in line is successful, but running MLKit or TFLite models from real time camera feed all day long makes *Dev A* overheat excessively. The best solution so far seems to be waiting for the trigger to come from an external device (*Dev B*) that operates independently.

Since *Dev B* may respond with some delay I need to communicate with it asynchronously, hence the reason for the question in the first place. While there are certainly several architectural nuances to discuss, the current root of the problem is that **I can't decide** (or rather *I don't know*) **how to handle the repeating "connection" with *Dev B* in a non-blocking way.**

I mean, can I just treat this issue like any other case where multithreading is needed, or the fact that the camera is involved might pose additional threats? The backpressure strategy is set to `STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST`, so in theory if the current call to `analyze()` hasn't finished yet the new frames are dropped and nothing bad happens even if inside the method I'm still waiting for the async call to *Dev B* to finish, or am I missing something?

```
var connected = false
lateinit var result: Boolean
var analysis1 = true
var analysis2 = true

override fun analyze() {
    if (!connected) {
        result = connectToDevice() // needs to be async
        connected = true
    }

    // need positive result to proceed, otherwise start over
    if (!result) {
        connected = false
        return   
    }     
    
    if (analysis1) {
        // perform analysis #1...

        analysis1 = false
        // when an analysis is done, exit early and perform next analysis on next frame
        return
    }

    if (analysis2) {
        // perform analysis #2...

        analysis2 = false
        // same as above
        return
    }

    // when all analyses are done, reset all flags to start over
    connected = false
    analysis1 = true
    analysis2 = true
}
```

Comment: `ImageAnalysis.setAnalyzer()` takes as an argument an Executor in which the analysis logic runs. Is there a specific reason you'd like not to block its thread when running the analysis? If your goal is to analyze multiple camera frames concurrently, it will take more than just making the analysis logic asynchronous to achieve it. So I guess my question is, what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: @HusaynHakeem I've added a more detailed explanation in the question. Sorry for the wall of text.

Comment: You last paragraph is correct, with `STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST`, frames will be dropped until the frame that's currently being analyzed is closed. Your asynchronous use case seems to be using something like callbacks to communicate, it shouldn't cause an issue inside your `Analyzer` as long as you make sure to clear resources once the camera's closed, e.g. when the lifecycle that's controlling the camera is stopped, the image provided to the `Analyzer` should be closed even if an analysis is still ongoing.

Comment: @HusaynHakeem Thanks, but how can I close the `ImageProxy` from anywhere and at anytime? Also, after reconsidering the problem and changing route slightly I've asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65834355/how-to-navigate-to-a-fragment-from-inside-cameraxs-analyze) that might actually have more in common with your latest proposal. As for the need of asynchronous code, I've completely scrapped the idea because my assumptions were wrong.