# Navigate to another fragment when picture is taken and saved with CameraX

Tags: kotlin, android-camerax

The goal is simple. When user takes a picture on Fragment1 and picture is saved, the app should navigate user to Fragment2. My problem, I don't know how to achieve it. I cannot navigate from camera thread (it is illegal), I need to do it from main thread. However, in the main thread I don't know when the camera thread is done. So basically, where/how should I realize it. I have tried a lot of different solutions, but nothing worked for me, this is why I am looking for a help from a community. Thanks in advance. My code for the camera is straight forward.

```
    private fun takePhoto() {

    // Get a stable reference of the modifiable image capture use case
    imageCapture?.let { imageCapture ->

        // Create output file to hold the image
        val fileName = SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME, Locale.US).format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + PHOTO_EXTENSION
        val photoFile = File(outputDirectory, fileName)

        // Setup image capture metadata
        val metadata = ImageCapture.Metadata().apply {

            // Mirror image when using the front camera
            //isReversedHorizontal = lensFacing == CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT
        }

        // Create output options object which contains file + metadata
        val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile)
            .setMetadata(metadata)
            .build()

        // Setup image capture listener which is triggered after photo has been taken
        imageCapture.takePicture(
            outputOptions, cameraExecutor, object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
                override fun onError(e: ImageCaptureException) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Photo capture failed: ${e.message}", e)
                }

                override fun onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                    val savedUri = output.savedUri ?: Uri.fromFile(photoFile)

                    Log.d(TAG, "Photo capture succeeded: $savedUri")

                    // If the folder selected is an external media directory, this is
                    // unnecessary but otherwise other apps will not be able to access our
                    // images unless we scan them using [MediaScannerConnection]
                    val mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton()
                        .getMimeTypeFromExtension(savedUri.toFile().extension)
                    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
                        context,
                        arrayOf(savedUri.toFile().absolutePath),
                        arrayOf(mimeType)
                    ) { _, uri ->
                        Log.d(TAG, "Image capture scanned into media store: $uri")
                    }

                    saveToFireStoreStorage(photoFile, fileName)
                    //remove file from app-specific storage, keep file only on Firestore
                    photoFile.delete()
                }
            })

        // We can only change the foreground Drawable using API level 23+ API
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

            // Display flash animation to indicate that photo was captured
            binding.root.postDelayed({
                binding.root.foreground = ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE)
                binding.root.postDelayed(
                    { binding.root.foreground = null }, ANIMATION_FAST_MILLIS)
            }, ANIMATION_SLOW_MILLIS)
        }
    }
}
```

I call takePhoto like this:

```
binding.cameraCaptureButton.setOnClickListener {
    takePhoto()
}
```

I have checked the similar question: [Navigating to another fragment from CameraX analyze() blocks current fragment's lifecycle and freezes the UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65834355/navigating-to-another-fragment-from-camerax-analyze-blocks-current-fragments)
But I don't want to use analyze block in the app and the answer is not applicable in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I would make the takePhoto() function return a boolean value, true in case picture is saved, and then:

```
binding.cameraCaptureButton.setOnClickListener {
    if (takePhoto()) {/* navigation logic* /}
}
```

Comment: Does not work, because everything under takePhoto is async thread.